# JSF EL expression renders question marks (?) for Chinese characters inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am using an EL expression inside JavaScript for rendering Chinese value.

```
alert('#{bundle.chinese}');
```

But it renders question marks (?) instead of actual characters.

When I use it outside a script tag in the same XHTML page, e.g.

```
<p>#{bundle.chinese}</p>
```

It renders the right chinese Characters. View source shows the html UTF encoded values `&....;`).

I am using JSF on Facelets.

Comment: Can you please clarify "renders question marks" a bit more? When you rightclick HTML page and view generated source, you see `alert('???');` instead of `alert('&1234;&1234;&1234;')` or so?

Comment: yes in the view source it shows alert('???')  for chinese charecters. For english charecters its working fine

Comment: That's odd... Btw, it's charActers, not charEcters ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I can't reproduce this with Mojarra 2.0.2 on Tomcat 6.0.20. Here's the JSF page I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <f:loadBundle basename="com.example.i18n.text" var="bundle" />
    <h:head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script>alert('#{bundle.chinese}');</script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p>#{bundle.chinese}</p>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And here is the contents of `com/example/i18n/text.properties`.

```
chinese=\u6C49\u8BED\uFF0F\u6F22\u8A9E\u002C\u0020\u534E\u8BED\uFF0F\u83EF\u8A9E\u0020\u006F\u0072\u0020\u4E2D\u6587
```

The generated HTML source is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script>alert('汉语／漢語, 华语／華語 or 中文');</script></head><body>
    <p>汉语／漢語, 华语／華語 or 中文</p></body>
</html>
```

Probably you're doing some stuff a bit differently and/or using a different JSF impl/version. Aren't you somewhere hardcoding/using a non-UTF-8 character encoding? Watch the IDE settings as well.

Comment: Thanks for the above input. 
The result above is the one which I am looking for. However there  are some differences. The characters (database) which I am getting from the jsf renderer is html encoded UTF (&#...;) which is rendered correctly everywhere except inside the script tag. I have included the xml tag and meta tag  in which I have set the charset to utf-8  but none of this is working. Is there any server level configuration that I need to change  or I have to add any page level tag??
ps:- My application is deployed on was 6.1

Comment: In the  above test just encode (in &#...; form) the data and then check what is being rendered.

Comment: Are you saying that the text is stored as XML entities (e.g. `&#1234;`) in the database? Why? Please clarify the technical specifications more so that we can try to reproduce this. As far you're only describing the symptoms, but you're not giving anything feasible to work with. How *exactly* are the characters stored? How *exactly* are you retrieving them? How *exactly* are you displaying them? Update your question to include a complete example like I did above in my answer.